# Firebase transaction in React Native

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, transactions, native

I've set up Firebase and it's all working fine. Now I want to increment a value when someone presses on a name, at the first moment I thought 'let's just update it'. But quickly I saw that this was not the right way. I'm creating a really simple multiplayer game, so there is a chance someone else presses this name at the same moment. This will give a problem.

I looked it up and found out that Firebase transaction is the right approach, I looked up some tutorials, and came up with the following code:

```
   const renderList = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <ListItem
                style={{
                    marginTop: 10,
                    width: 380,
                }}
                roundAvatar
                title={playerList[item].username}
                subtitle={item.subtitle}
                onPress={() => {
                    logIn(roomId, playerList[item].username)
                }}
            />
        )
    };


  const increasePress = () => {
            const myRef = firebase.database().ref('MP/rooms/testroom/participants/Max/')
            await firebase.firestore().runTransaction((transaction) => {
                const snapshot = await transaction.get(myRef);

                return snapshot.update(myRef,'press',snapshot.data().press + 1)
            });
        }


    useEffect(() => {
        ownParticipantRoom.update({
            username: username,
            host: isHost,
            press: 9,
            connected: 1,
        })
    }, [gamePercentage])
```

I know that the first reason this is not working, is because I'm using Await outside an async function. However I've never used this. How can I fix it?

Comment: I am pretty new to JS, but could you try amending `const increasePress = () => {` to `const increasePress = async () => {`?

Comment: Thanks, with what you said I don't get an error anymore. However I found a different way that does work. I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it using the following code:

```
    const increasePress = () => {
        const myRef = firebase.database().ref('MP/rooms/testroom/participants/Max/').child('press');
        myRef.transaction(function (currentPress) {
            return currentPress + 1
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit this answer to explain what is different from your original code, and why you think that helped? It is our experience that this writing approach is much more useful for future readers, who will not be as familiar with your code as you are. We also find that more substantial answers are more likely to get upvotes, too.